# pdf header with text boxes

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to have text boxes in the header of a pdf file? I'm sending a pdf file to multiple people and I want them to be able to write their names in those boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF supports [forms](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/collect-data-fillable-forms.html) which allows you to add text boxes and all sorts of other form fields which can then be printed or submitted online.

You can create PDFs with forms by using [Adobe Acrobat Professional](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/) or the free online tool [PDFescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/).  The open source [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/) desktop publishing application also supports PDF forms, but I'm not sure how well it can import an existing PDF file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried acrobat professional, but it doesn't allow me to put forms in the header.

Comment: @Baha:  If Acrobat Professional won't do it, it's likely the PDF format simply doesn't support it.  However, you can easily put a form field on one page and duplicate it across all pages, with the text entered in any one of them replicated to the rest.  [This help article explains how](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/8.0/Professional/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7df6.html), under *Duplicate a form field across multiple pages*.

Comment: @Baha:  As I said before, you can put a text box on every page for their name and when they type it in one it'll show up on the rest.  Just draw the text box in the header area.

Comment: Patches, this solution doesn't work for me because I'm trying to batch convert multiple docx files to pdf. But thanks for sharing this trick.